# Audit log for Docker

Tags: docker, audit

Can I be able to audit log the processes inside the docker in global log events so that process inside the docker?

What are the changes to be provided to include the log events of docker to be viewed in global?

Answer (score 0):

Docker currently only provides log access to single containers.

```
docker logs <container>
```

However there are solutions like the [ELK-Stack](https://github.com/willdurand/docker-elk) for centralized logging. See this [description](http://evanhazlett.com/2014/11/Logging-with-ELK-and-Docker/).

Comment: How to run the a process inside the docker container and view that process with global PID in the audit.log.How can we do that.Give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Sysdig](https://sysdig.com/let-light-sysdig-adds-container-visibility/) to see all logs:

$ sudo sysdig -pc -cspy_logs